# Find an explicit solution for $xy'+(x+\frac {1}{3})y=e^{-2x}y^{-2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Beginning with the differential equation:
$$xy'+(x+\frac {1}{3})y=e^{-2x}y^{-2}$$
Divide by $x$: $$y'+y+\frac {y}{3x}=e^{-2x}y^{-2}x^{-1}$$

Dividing by $y^{-2}$ gives: $$y^2y'+y^2y+\frac {1}{3xy}=e^{-2x}x^{-1}$$
Normally, for Bernoulli equations, one would substitute such that $v=y^2$ and $v'=2yy'$ but I seem to have simplified poorly.

Comment: Except in this case, it's $v=y^{1-(-2)}=y^3$.

Comment: Bernoulli equation
$$\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=Q(x)y^n$$
can be reduced to a linear equation by using $v=y^{1-n}$. Then, for the given equation, use $v=y^{1-(-2)}=y^3$.

Comment: your third step is wrong there should be y^3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$xy'+(x+\frac {1}{3})y=e^{-2x}y^{-2}$$
Multiply by $3y^2$:
$$3xy^2y'+(3x+1)y^3=3e^{-2x}$$
Let $\quad Y=y^3$ :
$$xY'+(3x+1)Y=3e^{-2x}$$
This is a linear ODE easy to solve :
$$Y=\frac{c}{xe^{3x}}+\frac{3}{xe^{2x}}$$
$$y(x)=\left(\frac{c}{xe^{3x}}+\frac{3}{xe^{2x}} \right)^{1/3}$$

Answer (score 3):

The ODE given is

$$xy'+ \left(x+\dfrac 13\right)y=e^{-2x}y^{-2}$$

I shall also divide it by $x$. So, the ODE becomes:

$$y'+\left(1+\dfrac{1}{3x}\right)y =\dfrac{e^{-2x}}{x}y^{-2}\tag 1$$

This is Bernoulli's ODE.

We substitute $v=y^{1-(-2)}=y^3$.

So, $\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\dfrac{1}{3v^{(2/3)}}\dfrac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx}$

$$\begin{align}(1)&\implies \dfrac{1}{3v^{(2/3)}}\dfrac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx}+\left(1+\dfrac{1}{3x}\right)v^{1/3}=\dfrac{e^{-2x}}{x}v^{-2/3}\\ &\implies \dfrac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx}+ 3\left(1+\dfrac{1}{3x}\right)v=3\dfrac{e^{-2x}}{x}\end{align}$$

I think you can take it from here.